# Why wont SFML Xcode load my .png file using C++?

Tags: c++, xcode, sfml

After finally being able to get SFML to work on Xcode, I have encountered another problem, that says my .png file cannot be loaded.

```
019-09-15 19:45:01.816739-0400 SFML Proj.[32379:2744427] MessageTracer: load_domain_whitelist_search_tree:73: Search tree file's format version number (0) is not supported
2019-09-15 19:45:01.816896-0400 SFML Proj.[32379:2744427] MessageTracer: Falling back to default whitelist
Failed to load image "res/img/mario.png". Reason: Unable to open file
Program ended with exit code: 9
```

[image: This is the path to my file:]

and this is what I put in for my file path for the texture:

```
sf::Texture texture;
texture.loadFromFile("res/img/mario.png");
```

can someone please help me?

Comment: Do you have a “Copy Bundle Resources” build phase?

Comment: My guess is that the image isn’t being copied into the bundle and if it is, you’re using the wrong path

Comment: If I remember correctly, you have to use Objective-C to get the path to the resources folder

Comment: Have a look at the `ResourcePath.hpp` and `ResourcePath.mm` files in [this tutorial](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-osx.php). Download those two files and embed them in your project.

Comment: After adding the image to the build phase, you should be able to do this `texture.loadFromFile(resourcePath() + “mario.png”);`

Answer (score 1):

In project settings, under the build phases tab, create a new "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase (if there isn't one already). Build phases are things that happen while the bundle is being built. "Copy Bundle Resources" copies files into the `Resources` folder of the bundle.

[image: screenshot]

Copy [ResourcePath.hpp](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SFML/SFML/489482a630c5286e488ffc270c10562809056d8e/tools/xcode/templates/SFML/SFML%20App.xctemplate/ResourcePath.hpp) and [ResourcePath.mm](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SFML/SFML/489482a630c5286e488ffc270c10562809056d8e/tools/xcode/templates/SFML/SFML%20App.xctemplate/ResourcePath.mm) into your project. The `resourcePath()` function returns the path to the resources folder in the bundle.

```
sf::Texture texture;
texture.loadFromFile(resourcePath() + "mario.png");
```

To verify that the file is in the bundle, find the bundle...

[image: screenshot]

then open the bundle...

[image: screenshot]

For more information, see [the tutorial](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-osx.php).

Comment: Good answer, however if you cannot load the main bundle you should throw an exception, rather than meekly write a log message, as the world if effectively over for that game.

Comment: Thanks for helping... I know it has been a while since you have answered this question, but I still don't completely understand what you are explaining. I went to a tech camp that really didn't teach me what all of this background stuff was, so I'm sorry that I don't understand it. When you said to copy the .hpp and .mm files into my project, did you mean add them to the Copy Bundle Resources in Build Phases? And there isn't an option to show package contents, because the file under products seems to be a file with a preview that says exec, not a .app file. Sorry to bother you!

Comment: @DavidMorse The .hpp and .mm files are source files, not assets. Just drag them into the project right next to `main.cpp` and the others. It sounds like your target is a Command Line Tool rather than a Cocoa App. Are you using the SFML Xcode project templates (also available in the tutorial I linked)? If you want a project with assets (images, sounds, fonts, etc) then your best bet is to switch over to a Cocoa App target. Otherwise you can do things the "Windows way" and put all your assets in a folder next to your executable.

Comment: @DavidMorse To switch over to a Cocoa App, just create a new project and select "App" (or "SFML App" if you're using the project templates). Then just copy everything over. If you need me to be more specific, I can update my answer.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I was finally able to get the templates to work, and selected the SFML app template. When I try to run it, it comes up with an error: "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with nonzero exit code" When I click on it: it shows this in the All Issues section: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SA67Tnd7Wa6omAerR3bWoDFH2zu7oWEU/view?usp=sharing I also do not have a Frameworks folder, like the screenshot shows. Sorry for answering a while after you do - I can only do this if I have any extra time. If I can get this to work, then I will finally be able to create something fun!

Comment: After using the template, the file under products is a .app file, so that problem is fixed. Again I can't say thank you enough.

Comment: `/Users/SFML/Desktop`? I think that should be `/Users/David/Desktop` instead. It looks like you wrote `SFML` somewhere in the build phase. It sounds like you're getting close!